# How to split weekly data in mysql into daily number

Tags: mysql, sql

I have in a database values available in a weekly split.
For example, two columns: 2019-03-10, 7000

First one is a week, the other one is a number

what I would like to achieve, using SELECT query, is to divide this number by 7 and display as 7 days of this week, so the result would be

```
2019-03-10   -   1000
2019-03-11   -   1000
2019-03-12   -   1000
2019-03-13   -   1000
2019-03-14   -   1000
2019-03-15   -   1000
2019-03-16   -   1000
```

I was not able to build any query, I am even not sure if this is doable ,but will be thankful for any suggestions

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: hey Nick, MySQL 5.3

Comment: Consider doing this kind of thing in application code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this result by `JOIN`ing your weekly data table to a generated table containing the values 0 to 6 (for the number of days relative to the week start). You can create each days date by adding the day number of the start of week, and the quantity by dividing the weekly number by 7. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE weekly (week_start DATE,
                     quantity INT);

INSERT INTO weekly VALUES
('2019-03-10', 7000),
('2019-03-03', 4444);

SELECT w.week_start + INTERVAL d.day DAY AS `date`,
       w.quantity / 7 AS quantity
FROM weekly w
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS day
            UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3
            UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6) d
ORDER BY `date`
```

Output:

```
date        quantity
2019-03-03  634.8571
2019-03-04  634.8571
2019-03-05  634.8571
2019-03-06  634.8571
2019-03-07  634.8571
2019-03-08  634.8571
2019-03-09  634.8571
2019-03-10  1000
2019-03-11  1000
2019-03-12  1000
2019-03-13  1000
2019-03-14  1000
2019-03-15  1000
2019-03-16  1000
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dFfCkPk1YwKWrma75F2PXj/0)