# Query to return daily data for variable frequency aggregation

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a database that stores aggregated budget transactions with a week ending date. The frequency of these transactions varies (e.g. weekly, bi-weekly, tri-weekly, quad-weekly). It is represented in the Project database table by the 'report_frequency' field.

I am trying to write an SQL query that will pull all of the data separated to Daily. If I were to do this with a script, I would of course check the projects report frequency first, then do the math. However, I am wanting to put this SQL statement into Power Bi for reporting purposes. If this can't be done with an SQL statement, I'm open to any recommendations.

I've found solutions that get close:

- [How to split weekly data in mysql into daily number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55319491/how-to-split-weekly-data-in-mysql-into-daily-number)
- https://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2011-07-30/mysql-row-generator

However, neither of these account for a variable number of days for the aggregated data.

Here's my attempt at a minimal example:

**Database**

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `frequency_test` ;
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `frequency_test` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `frequency_test`;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `project`;
CREATE TABLE `project` (
  `project_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `report_frequency` INTEGER NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`project_id`)
);

LOCK TABLES `project` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `project` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `project` VALUES (1,14);
INSERT INTO `project` VALUES (2,7);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `project` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `budget`;
CREATE TABLE `budget` (
  `budget_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `project_id` int NOT NULL,
  `entry_date` date NOT NULL,
  `hours` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL,
  `dollars` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`budget_id`),
  KEY `project_id` (`project_id`)
);

LOCK TABLES `budget` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `budget` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `budget` VALUES (1,1,'2021-07-18',80,1000);
INSERT INTO `budget` VALUES (2,1,'2021-08-01',80,1500);
INSERT INTO `budget` VALUES (3,2,'2021-07-04',60,600);
INSERT INTO `budget` VALUES (4,2,'2021-08-11',40,800);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `budget` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

**Query for 7 days (using first link above)**

```
SELECT
-- project data
p.project_id,
p.report_frequency,
-- period data
b.budget_id,
b.entry_date,
b.hours,
b.dollars,
-- calculated data
entry_date + INTERVAL d.day DAY daily_date,
hours / (7 * p.report_frequency / 7) AS daily_hours,
dollars / (7 * p.report_frequency / 7) AS daily_dollars
FROM budget b
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS day
            UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3
            UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6) d
JOIN project p ON p.project_id = b.project_id;
```

**Query for n days (using second link above) - Does not work.**
error: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'p.frequency' in 'where clause'

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW generator_16
AS SELECT 0 n 
UNION ALL SELECT 1  
UNION ALL SELECT 2  
UNION ALL SELECT 3  
UNION ALL SELECT 4
UNION ALL SELECT 5  
UNION ALL SELECT 6   
UNION ALL SELECT 7
UNION ALL SELECT 8  
UNION ALL SELECT 9   
UNION ALL SELECT 10 
UNION ALL SELECT 11 
UNION ALL SELECT 12
UNION ALL SELECT 13
UNION ALL SELECT 14 
UNION ALL SELECT 15;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW generator_256
AS SELECT ( ( hi.n << 4 ) | lo.n ) AS n
     FROM generator_16 lo, generator_16 hi;
     
SELECT
-- project data
p.project_id,
p.report_frequency,
-- period data
b.budget_id,
b.entry_date,
b.hours,
b.dollars,
-- calculated data
entry_date + INTERVAL d.day DAY daily_date,
hours / (7 * p.report_frequency / 7) AS daily_hours,
dollars / (7 * p.report_frequency / 7) AS daily_dollars
FROM budget b
CROSS JOIN (SELECT n
  FROM generator_256
 WHERE n < p.frequency) d
JOIN project p ON p.project_id = b.project_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move that WHERE clause outside (and it should be `p.report_frequency` not `p.frequency`):

```
SELECT
    b.project_id,
    b.budget_id,
    b.entry_date,
    b.entry_date + INTERVAL d.day DAY daily_date,
    b.hours / (7 * p.report_frequency / 7) AS daily_hours,
    b.dollars / (7 * p.report_frequency / 7) AS daily_dollars
FROM budget b JOIN project p ON p.project_id = b.project_id
CROSS JOIN (SELECT n day
  FROM generator_256) d
WHERE d.day < p.report_frequency  
ORDER BY `b`.`budget_id`, `daily_date` ASC;
```

According to you need modify `daily_hours` and `daily_dollars` columns if they should depend on `p.report_frequency`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that is what you want. To generate days numbers from 0 to N in MySql >= 8.0 you can use a recursive query.

You need change 15 in my query for the max number you want.

```
WITH RECURSIVE days AS (SELECT 0 AS n
                     
                        UNION ALL 
                     
                        SELECT n + 1
                        FROM days
                        WHERE n < 15)
                     
                     
SELECT *
FROM days;
```

Using it in your **query for 7 days**:

```
WITH RECURSIVE days AS (SELECT 0 AS n
                     
                        UNION ALL 
                     
                        SELECT n + 1
                        FROM days
                        WHERE n < 6)
                        
                        
SELECT
-- project data
p.project_id,
p.report_frequency,
-- period data
b.budget_id,
b.entry_date,
b.hours,
b.dollars,
-- calculated data
entry_date + INTERVAL days.n DAY daily_date,
hours / (7 * p.report_frequency / 7) AS daily_hours,
dollars / (7 * p.report_frequency / 7) AS daily_dollars
FROM budget b
CROSS JOIN days
JOIN project p ON p.project_id = b.project_id;
```